# How to modify property of companion object in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, properties, edit, koin, companion-object

I have a class that contain companion object like below.

```
class Customization {
    companion object {
        var become_member = ""
    }
}
```

I want to modify property of companion object at runtime. I will add hundreds of property in this class. So I have to do  dynamic. I used this method and getting error like below.

```
fun customizeStrings(key:String, value:String){
    var buckTypes = Customization::class
    var buck = Customization()
    var variableToInvoke  = buckTypes.companionObject!!.memberProperties.find {
        it.name == key
    }
    println(variableToInvoke!!.name)

    if (variableToInvoke  is KMutableProperty<*>) {
     variableToInvoke.setter.call(buck, value) 
    }

}
```

I'm getting this error.

**org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Factory:'com.screen.splash.SplashViewModel']**

Can someone explain to me where is my fault? Or show me another way to modify property of companion object in Kotlin?

Comment: what must go here as first argument? -> `setter.call(Customization.Companion, value)`. However I don't know what the error has relevance with this... And probably instead of accessing companion from its parent, you can directly target companion: `Customization.Companion::class`.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Thanks for your reply. Interesting but It worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

As @AnimeshSahu said in comment, It worked clearly. If there is getting error people like me, try to access directly target companion like `Customizationn.Companion::class`. It's saved my day.